# Passing JS object property that starts with a number to Freemaker

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, freemarker, string-interpolation

I am trying to pass a string to freemarker templating engine. The code below is part of coffeescript.

The following string works just fine.

```
${passThrough('
    [#if (Contact.customFields.customField)?? && Contact.customFields.customField?trim != ""]
        ${Contact.customFields.customField}
    [#else]
        If you see this you are good
    [/#if]
')}
```

but I want to pass

```
Contact.customFields["1customField"]
```

I tried with escaping the double quotes but that didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks much!

Comment: Thanks for the formatting @GG.

Comment: This looks like a big FreeMarker interpolation that contains a string as the argument to `passThrough`, which string contains some further `${...}`-s. The `#if`-s and such will be just text there, as those have no special meaning inside a FreeMarker string. I don't see Coffeescript anywhere.